# Get the number of files in a directory within Gulp.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

So far I have tried using the `glob-fs` package like so:

```
  let cssFileCount;
  glob.readdir('public/css/*.css', function (err, files) {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    console.log(files);
    cssFileCount = (files.length);
  });
```

This works perfectly fine with the path to my JS files `public/js/*.js` however when I use my `public/css/*.css` it returns an empty array although the directory has css files in it. When I use the js path it returns an array with a list of files. I then use `.length` to check the number of files.

Is there any other way I can check the number of files within a directory using Globbing?

Comment: Could you please add more details? Please elaborate the `it doesn't work.` part. What do you expect vs. actual result. How is your folder structure? Do you expect it to work in depth recursively, because then you probably just need to specify this using `public/css/**/*.css`

Comment: Hi, I have tried using `public/css/**/*.css` however it still returns an empty array. I'm wondering if there are any other ways to count the number of files in the directory as it simply can't read that folder for some reason.  I have also updated the original question, thanks.

Comment: You can try using the basic node `fs.readdr` (see https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback)

Comment: I've tried using it however passing the path using the glob syntax doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative is to simply use the node's standard file system api with a basic filter as such:

```
 const fs = require('fs');
 const path = require('path')
 fs.readdr('public/css', function(err, files) {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    const cssFiles = files.filter(file => path.extname(file).toLowerCase() === '.css'));
    console.log(cssFiles);
    cssFileCount = (cssFiles.length);
 });
```

You cannot use glob on this approach, but from your problem statement it's not truly needed, as your file filter is quite basic (i.e. extension).

Comment: Thanks! There a few syntax errors in there however I have managed to get it to work. Thanks for explaining this to me, I have literally just started using node.js. I find it very strange that the `glob-fs` package didn't work for the CSS directory however this does.